# AWS Cognito - Why does changing my bundle id cause a ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

**Quick Background:**

I am making an Android app and an iOS app where both use AWS (user pools, S3, etc.). As the story goes, I had changed the versions of AWS dependencies in my Android project from "2.2.+" to "2.6.7" (the latest at the time of writing this). In the process of changing the code to account for the differences (like IdentityManager being moved to a different package) I also messed with AWS settings like roles, permissions, etc. in an effort to troubleshoot the new exceptions I was getting. Everything is now normal with the Android app.

**Problem:**

However, without me having touched my iOS app's source code, it wasn't working anymore. The app is based-off of the [CognitoYourUserPoolsSample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Swift), and is changed so that a user signs in and the app segues to the main view controller where a file is downloaded from S3.

Now I am getting a `ResourceNotFoundException` when trying to download that file. The exception references an identity id not Naturally I assumed it was because I tampered with AWS settings, but, by chance, *I discovered that changing the bundle id back to that of the sample* (`com.amazonaws.CognitoYourUserPoolsSample`) *makes it work like it used to*. How is this possible?

**Stacktrace:**

```
Error downloading: Optional([my s3 file]) Error: Error 
Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=10 "(null)" 
UserInfo={message=Identity '[my identity id]' not found., 
__type=ResourceNotFoundException}
```

EDIT: I started over from that sample (linked above) in a new project and *moved all of my custom swift files and storyboard into the new project*, and it works as expected regardless of the bundle id. What's going on here?

Comment: This sounds like some value is in your keychain or user defaults, namespaced by the old bundle id.

Comment: @ozzieozumo Could you explain? How might I remedy this?

Comment: You asked "How is this possible?".  There's a lot of things that could be going on here.  Think about it ... if AWS stores the old BundleID in any persistent store (key chain, user defaults) and tries to use the new BundleID to look it up later, you will see different behavior.  If you don't want to test for this condition (changed bundleID), you can reset your simulator after changing the bundleID .. that will force your app (and AWS) to act as if newly installed. Pinpointing the failure would require a lot more info.

Comment: @ozzieozumo I started iOS development only months ago, and I'm not too familiar with mac. I know basic things about the keychain, though. Also, I'm not using the simulator at all, and I tried uninstalling+cleaning+building+running and it's the same error. I'll look into a way to manually purge the keychain of related keys I'll look into that.